# Mocking properties to test validation methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to test a method that is validating that some application properties have been set. I'm trying to mock the call that fetches the settings:

```
public interface IMyLogic{
    string GetSetting(string key);
    bool AreSettingsValid(); 
}

public class MyLogic: IMyLogic {
    public string GetSetting(string key){
        return (string) Properties.Settings.Default[key];
    }

    public bool AreSettingsValid(){
        return GetSetting("Setting1") != null && GetSetting("Setting2") != null;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyLogicTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyLogic_AreSettingsValidIsTrue_WhenValuesAreSet(){
        var mockMyLogic = Mock<IMyLogic>();
        mockMyLogic.Setup(m=>m.GetSetting(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("something");
        Assert(true, mockMyLogic.Object.AreSettingsValid());
    }
}
```

This is not working. How do I get `AreSettingsValid()` to trigger the mocked call to `GetSetting`?

Comment: this example is incomplete. provide a [mcve]

Comment: You shouldn't be using a mock as your code under test.  It seems like what you really want to test is `MyLogic` but mock out the `Properties` which would require some type of wrapper.  Maybe push the `GetSettings` into another class that you inject into `MyLogic` and can then mock.

Comment: @nkosi I thought that I had been very thorough and concise, and I'm not aware of anything that is missing. Perhaps whatever you think is missing is the cause of the problem I'm trying to solve?

Comment: @juharr I'm trying to test the logical validation in `AreSettingsValid()` is correct. This method is validating properties have been set within the same method.

Comment: @MarkCooper We do not know the interface provided, all the members of that example class are private, There is more but that would require wasting time trying to find out from you what is what. Hence incomplete and unclear which would result in people providing suggestions only for you you to say that is not what I meant then a a lot of back and forth trying to clarify what it is you actually want

Comment: @MarkCooper Yes, and if you want to test that you need an instance of `MyLogic`, not a mock of `IMyLocic`

Comment: Where is `Properties` defined? Is it static? And as others have pointed out, it is not clear what your class under test is since you are mocking everything.

Comment: @Nkosi: thanks. I have added additional information
@NightOwl888: `Properties` is the user settings values, but I think this is irrelevent as I'm trying to mock this call out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the IMyLogic in a different class to mock it and fake the output. For example:

```
class MyLogic
{
    bool AreSettingsValid(IMySettings mySettings){
        return mySettings.GetSetting("Setting1") != null &&
               mySettings.GetSetting("Setting2") != null;
    }
}

class MySettings: IMySettings {
    string GetSetting(string key){
        return (string) Properties.Settings.Default[key];
    }

}

[TestClass]
class MyLogicTest 
{
    [TestMethod]
    void MyLogic_AreSettingsValidIsTrue_WhenValuesAreSet(){
        var mockMySettings = Mock<IMySettings>();

        mockMySettings.Setup(m=>
            m.GetSetting(It.IsAny<string())).Returns("something");


        var myLogic = new MyLogic();

        Assert(true, myLogic.AreSettingsValid(mySettings.Object));
    }
}
```

You want to "mock" the interfaces that are used within your class under test, not the mock itself.

In the code above I have added a new class that represents the settings. Now I can mock the interface that class implements to mock what the GetSettings() call will do i.e. return the setting. I can now test the MyLogic class without having to rely on the Properties.Settings.Default[key] code as that relies on something external being present which you don't really want to rely on when doing unit tests.

Hope that helps?

Comment: I think your naming is a bit off.  It would make more sense for `MySettings` to handle `GetSetting` and `MyLogic` to handle `AreSettingsValid`, but otherwise this is more or less what the OP should be doing.

Comment: Ha ha ! Very true! I shall update the answer. Thanks for letting me know :)